# integral involving square root using complex methods: what choice of path?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm asked to compute using complex methods the following integral:
$$ I(a)= \int_0^1 \mathrm{d}x \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2-a^2},$$
where $a>1.$

What I know is the following: for $|z|<1,$ the function
$$\sqrt{1-z^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\frac12}{k}(-)^kz^{2k}$$
is analytic; regarding the denominator, we have to worry about poles for $z=\pm a$ and at $\infty.$

My QUESTIONs are the following:

1. I'm not sure about the best choice of integration path: can anyone
   help?
2. morever, is it necessary to cut a branch in the
   square root to compute this?
3. is it possible to do this without
   using complex methods at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. and 2. : make the cut along the interval $[-1,1]$ and use a closed path going once above and once below the interval; you get twice the integral you want to compute (find the result using residue theorem - you'll need to include also the residue at infinity)

For 3. - sure, use e.g. Euler's substitution to get an integral of a rational function

Comment: thanks, so the suggested path should pass between say 1 and $a$?

Comment: i.e., a dogbone?

Comment: @Nicolo: yes, that's a good name for the path